# "It was a stoney castle kind of thing." VS "It was kind of a stoney castle. --- Is the 1st sentence as valid as the 2nd one?

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-structure, collocations

This is from a native speaker who is describing an imaginary house:

**"So, it was a stony, log cabin(y) castle kind of thing."** [Improve your english-Ronnie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uNpTKVsRZmY) (see:2:58-3:13)

Subtitles show different texts for the part in paranthesis. So I can't be sure whether she says **"cabin or cabiny"**.

The expression in the sentence **"X kind of thing"** reminded me the structure **"kind of X."** If I apply it to this sentence, it would basically be:

**"So, it was kind of a stony castle."** (unclear words removed)

To me, they seem to have the same meaning, however, I am not sure because I don't often see the structure **"noun+kind of a thing"** as in the case of **"stony castle kind of a thing"** rather than **"kind of a stony castle"?**

So, do you think **"stony castle kind of a thing"** is as valid as **"kind of a stony castle?"**?

Comment: To my mind, *a stony, log, cabiny, castle kind of thing* is "gibberish". I wouldn't advise trying to learn English from any source that encourages you to make up terms like that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - it's very very very casual. My neighbour's pet is a spanielly, poodly, beagly kind of dog. Royal Navy sailors are fond of something called 'Hammy-cheesy-eggy'.

Comment: A log cabin and a castle are two completely different **kinds of** building, so the description is quite illogical (though she is describing a dream, and dreams often are illogical). **An X kind of thing** is a very informal way of saying "a thing vaguely resembling an X".

Comment: @FumbleFingers People speak like that. They add y to all sorts of things as Michael has shown. And part of becoming **really fluent** in a language involves mastering this kind of thing. If someone has an advanced level, this is exactly the kind of question they should or might be asking.

Comment: @Lambie, Exactly. I couldn't agree more.

Comment: yunus, now I'm thinking advanced +. Like an interpreter who pays attention to the tiniest details when improving their mastery of a language. Cheers.

Comment: One outstanding example is "The Doctor"'s description of the nature of time not as a solid, static construct but "a big ball of wibbly wobbly, timey wimey stuff."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. So, it was a stony, log cabin, castle kind of thing.
2. So, it was kind of a stony log cabin castle.

Question: Do you think "stony castle kind of a thing" is as valid as "kind of a stony castle?" and they have the same meaning?

Yes, they are both valid but **can** mean slightly different things...
*A/an x kind of thing.
*A kind of [adjective] noun.

**a stony castle kind of thing**: means it was **like a stony castle**.

WHEREAS:
**a kind of stony castle** means the castle was not made of some other building material. For example: It was a kind of wooden castle. But it can **also be**: it was sort of stony.

Another example:
The shawl was a woolly kind of thing. [like wool]
The shawl was a kind of woolly thing. [as opposed to silky or cottony.]

HOWEVER,
Sometimes in speech, they can mean the same thing as mentioned above and here.
The dirty clothes on the floor were a smelly kind of thing.
The dirty clothes on the floor were kind of a smelly thing.

OR NOT
The heap of clothes were a kind of cotton.

Conclusion: when the noun *kind* means sort or type (a kind of [adj] thing), there is a distinction between the two. But only the speech context will make clear which is meant. Also, when *kind of* is not preceded by a, it won't mean sort or type. *It was kind of stormy outside*.

Comment: @Yunus A general simplified rule of thumb: "kind of [adj]" = "somewhat [adj]"; "[adj] kind of a [noun]" = "[adj] type or category of a [noun]." But note, delete the adj from the last construct and it goes back to "somewhat." "He was kind of a jerk" = "He was [somewhat, sort of] a jerk." But "He was the sleaziest kind of con man" = "Of all types of con men, he was of the sleaziest variety."